# Combining the sum of multiple columns, of multiple tables, in one query/table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have four tables with identical fields (geography, q1, q2, q3, q4). I need to find the sum of the quarters for each of the four tables and produce a new table with the geography, sum of table 1, sum of table 2, sum of table 3, sum of table 4.

I can get each sum individually, but can't figure out how to combine them into one table. Below is the working code for one table, A:

```
SELECT [A].Geography, 
       Sum([A].[q1])+Sum([A].[q2])+Sum([A].[q3])+Sum([A].[q4]) AS TSUM
FROM [A]
GROUP BY [A].Geography
ORDER BY [A].Geography;
```

Comment: Do you have a table of available geographies?  Otherwise, this is rather painful to do in MS Access (typically requiring an auxiliary view or temporary table).

Comment: I do not, but I could make one. Would it just have the possible geographies? How would I do it with that table?

Comment: So in your final result set, do you want one row with five columns, one row with seventeen columns or four rows with five columns?

Comment: Five columns, and one row for each geography in the original tables

Comment: one column for each geografy, ok. But the other 4 columns, what information will have? q1, q2,q3, q4? or Tsum(A), Tsum(B), Tsum(C), Tsum(D)? Add some data sample and expected results, please. And name the columns acording

Comment: I need to find the sum of the quarters for each of the four tables and produce a new table with the geography, sum of table 1, sum of table 2, sum of table 3, sum of table 4.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join all tables by `Geography`, retrieving their aggregated column sums. Below assumes all Geographies are the same in all tables with table A as the matching source:

```
SELECT [A].Geography, 
       Sum([A].[q1])+Sum([A].[q2])+Sum([A].[q3])+Sum([A].[q4]) AS TSUM_A,
       Sum([B].[q1])+Sum([B].[q2])+Sum([B].[q3])+Sum([B].[q4]) AS TSUM_B,
       Sum([C].[q1])+Sum([C].[q2])+Sum([C].[q3])+Sum([C].[q4]) AS TSUM_C,
       Sum([D].[q1])+Sum([D].[q2])+Sum([D].[q3])+Sum([D].[q4]) AS TSUM_D

FROM (([A] 
INNER JOIN [B] ON [A].Geography = [B].Geography) 
INNER JOIN [C] ON [A].Geography = [C].Geography) 
INNER JOIN [D] ON [A].Geography = [D].Geography

GROUP BY [A].Geography
ORDER BY [A].Geography;
```

Should Geographies differ in all four tables, consider this workaround, using a derived table union query of all geographies across all tables (`UNION` returns distinct values vs `UNION ALL`) and then `LEFT JOINs` all tables, A-D. Of course this derived table of distinct geography records can be a saved Access query referenced in same place in `FROM` clause. Do note, in this approach, NULL values will appear in rows where geographies do not appear in particular table.

```
SELECT main.Geography, 
       Sum([A].[q1])+Sum([A].[q2])+Sum([A].[q3])+Sum([A].[q4]) AS TSUM_A,
       Sum([B].[q1])+Sum([B].[q2])+Sum([B].[q3])+Sum([B].[q4]) AS TSUM_B,
       Sum([C].[q1])+Sum([C].[q2])+Sum([C].[q3])+Sum([C].[q4]) AS TSUM_C,
       Sum([D].[q1])+Sum([D].[q2])+Sum([D].[q3])+Sum([D].[q4]) AS TSUM_D

FROM (((     
       (SELECT Geography FROM A 
        UNION SELECT Geography FROM B 
        UNION SELECT Geography FROM C
        UNION SELECT Geography FROM D) As main

LEFT JOIN [A] ON [main].Geography = [A].Geography)
LEFT JOIN [B] ON [main].Geography = [B].Geography) 
LEFT JOIN [C] ON [main].Geography = [C].Geography) 
LEFT JOIN [D] ON [main].Geography = [D].Geography

GROUP BY [main].Geography
ORDER BY [main].Geography;
```

*Take care to handle parentheses around join clauses as they are required by MS Access SQL.*

Comment: Thank you for your response! In theory it makes sense and looks good, but when I run it (the second option since geographies are different) I run into a overflow error. I assume that is something wrong with the code since there are about 1500 records per table and that shouldn't be too much (new to access so I could be wrong)

Comment: I tested this in MS Access. As mentioned, try creating a separate union query and used that in `FROM` clause. Also, is Geography a short text or long text (i.e., memo field). If the later, then no joins should be used on such an unlimited length field. Do you have a `geographyid` available?

Comment: `SELECT [main].Geography FROM (((
(select geography from [Claims Assumed]
        UNION SELECT Geography FROM [Claims Ceded]
        UNION SELECT Geography FROM [Premium Assumed]
        UNION SELECT Geography FROM [Premiums Ceded]) As main
LEFT JOIN [Claims Assumed] ON [main].Geography = [Claims Assumed].Geography)
LEFT JOIN [Claims Ceded] ON [main].Geography = [Claims Ceded].Geography)
LEFT JOIN [Premium Assumed] ON [main].Geography = [Premium Assumed].Geography)
LEFT JOIN [Premiums Ceded] ON [main].Geography = [Premiums Ceded].Geography
GROUP BY [main].Geography
ORDER BY [main].Geography;`

Comment: Sorry for the terrible formatting, but character limit :(. That is the subquery I made. When I call it in the main query, it does not work. I get an "[Claims Assumed].q1 could be referring to more than one table listed in the query"

Comment: That column is not in above query. Feel free to write query by editing your original post and not in comments.